# Java Array skipping Outputs?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, output

I'm currently working on an assignment for my programming class and I cannot figure out why my output is coming out wrong.

We are supposed to "Print the “Difference” of population from the previous year. (Of course, this value is blank for the first year in the list.)
Use format control to print the values for Year, Population value and Difference from previous year. "

And my teacher gave us what the output is supposed to look like:

Desired Output:

[image: Desired Output]

But I keep getting this:

My Output:

[image: My Output]

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class AssignmentOne
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // Array Version
        ArrayVersion();
        System.out.println("Finished Array Version of Assignment");
    }

    // Method for ArrayVersion
    public static void ArrayVersion() throws IOException
    {
        // Year as variables
        int year = 1950;
        final int ARRAY_SIZE = 41;

        // Array to use for Population data
        int[] population =  new int[40];

        // Call the method to get data into array
        population = getDataFromFile("USPopulation.txt");

        if(population == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Population did not load");
            return;
        }



        // Output
        System.out.println("This is the Simple Array Version of \nPopulation Data US");
        System.out.println("\nYear \tPopulation \tDifference");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.printf("%d \t%,d,000\n", year, population[0]);
        for(int i = 1; i < population.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%d \t%,d,000 \t%,d,000 \n", ++year, population[i], Math.abs(population[i] - population[++i]));
        }


        // Calculating the average + displaying it
        int sum = 0;
        for(int g = 0; g < population.length; g++)
        {
            sum += population[g];
        }
        int average;
        average = sum / population.length;
        System.out.println("Average:" + average);


    }
    // Method to get data from specified "filename" into an array of ints
    public static int[] getDataFromFile(String USPopulation) throws IOException
    {

        // Array to use for Population data
        // Opening file
        File file = new File("E:/Programming 2/Assignment 1/src/USPopulation.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);


         int fileSize = 0;
         while(inputFile.hasNext())
         {
             inputFile.nextInt();
             fileSize++; 
         }

         Scanner input2 = new Scanner(file);
         int[] fileData = new int[fileSize];
         for(int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
         {
             fileData[i] = input2.nextInt();
         }
        // System.out.println(fileData[40]);


         // return the array fileData
         return fileData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
population[++i]
```

There's your problem.

The prefixed increment simply increments the value of `i` before it gets the value, where `i++` gets the value then increments `i`.

Just change it to `population[i+1]` and you'll be good. :P

Edit:

```
for(int i = 1; i < population.length; i++)
{
System.out.printf("%d \t%,d,000 \t%,d,000 \n", ++year, population[i], population[i] - population[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: I've tried that except I get this error message: 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 41
 at AssignmentOne.ArrayVersion(AssignmentOne.java:48)
 at AssignmentOne.main(AssignmentOne.java:10)

Comment: Try changing for(int i = 1; i < population.length; i++) to int i = 0.

Comment: Yea I tried that and it still gives me the out of bounds error

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem is in this line:

```
  System.out.printf("%d \t%,d,000 \t%,d,000 \n", ++year, population[i], Math.abs(population[i] - population[++i]));
```

First, using `++i` bumps your loop counter `i` one extra time per iteration, so you're only looking at *every other* year.  No doubt you were trying to find the difference between one year's population and that of the *next* year; the correct way to look at next year's population would have been `population[i+1]`.  But, as you say, using `population[i+1]` eventually gives you `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Well, that's because when `i` is pointing to the last year, `i+1` points beyond the end of the array of population data.

The second problem, then, is that you really want to be finding the difference between each year's population and that of the *previous* year: `population[i] - population[i - 1]`.  So now, when `i` points at the last year, `i-1` will still be within the array bounds, and because your loop actually starts with `i == 1`, `i - 1` will *still* be a valid index.